# BottomSheetDialog fills the background instead of dimming it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-bottomsheetdialog

[image]

As you can see the part on top of the dialog is entirely white and not dimmed as it should be by default

I tried messing with styles, making windowBackground and Background transparent also doing it programatically. I tried making it in a new clean project and it worked correctly without any modifications whatsoever, as far as i can tell it should be default behavior and it's not the emulator/device problem as it worked with the new project. Here's the code

```
itemNotification.setOnClickListener {
    notificationsBottomSheetDialog.show()
}
notificationsBottomSheetBinding = FragmentNotificationsBottomSheetBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
notificationsBottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), style.CustomBottomSheetDialog)
notificationsBottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
notificationsBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(notificationsBottomSheetBinding.root)
```

Bottom sheet layout.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/core_padding_16"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/core_vertical_margin_16"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/core_vertical_margin">
<other stuff but not empty>
```

All the styles

```
CustomBottomSheetDialog:
    parent = ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog
    bottomSheetStyle = @style/CustomBottomSheet => @style/CustomBottomSheet

CustomBottomSheet:
    parent = Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet
    shapeAppearanceOverlay = @style/CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog

CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog:
    cornerFamily = rounded
    cornerSizeTopRight = 16dp
    cornerSizeTopLeft = 16dp
    cornerSizeBottomRight = 0dp
    cornerSizeBottomLeft = 0dp
    android:windowSoftInputMode = adjustResize
```

It also doesn't have rounded corners on top without the style even though in the new app it did, initializing it without the style still does the same white background

The dialog is called from a fragment if that makes a difference

Comment: You should show us the style that you are using. i.e. what is the `CustomBottomSheetDialog`?

Comment: Add a back color to `CustomBottomSheet:` style. (I am not familiar with compose mode).

Answer (score 0):

You could try by setting within onCreate a style this way

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL,R.style.SaveBottomSheetDialogStyle) }
```

Then provide a style in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="SaveBottomSheetDialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/ModalStyle.Transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

The XML can be as you desire with a background.xml file added to you view

Comment: This requires me to make a BSFragmentDialog right? Here i'm using a simple BSDialog

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

to your Bottomsheet root layout.

Comment: This did not help

Comment: Try to change back color by adding `android:background="@color/red"` and see the result.

Comment: i clarified the styles, still this did not help even the colors didn't change